# Send file from C# Server to AS3 AIR Clients using Sockets in a Local Network - with sample

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, sockets, air

I want to send a file from a C# server to a AS3 Flash Client. My C# server code for sending the file is something like this:

```
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
sock.Bind(ipEnd);
sock.Listen(100);
//clientSock is the socket object of client, so we can use it now to transfer data to client
Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

// This part gets the file and send the data in bytearray
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("send/mypicture.jpg");
clientSock.Send(fileData);
```

Now I need a as3 client. I found this: http://flasharp.blogspot.pt/2010/03/socket-serverclient-chat.html and I constructed something like this:

```
public function Main():void {
    ...
    socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
    ...
}

function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var file:File;
    var fs:FileStream;
    var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    // Check if socket has data
    if(socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
        while(socket.bytesAvailable) {
            // read the socket data into the fileData
            socket.readBytes(fileData,0,0);
        }
    }
    file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("teste.jpg");
    fs = new FileStream();
    fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    // Writing the file
    fs.writeBytes(fileData);
    fs.close();
}
```

I've managed to send and receive a file, but it only saves up to 50kbs, anything bigger and you just gest a file with that size.

Any thoughts on how to transfer a file with any size?

Comment: Doing this with sockets is an invitation to a world of pain. You'll need to serve a socket policy file in order to authorize the client to make socket connections in the first place. What's wrong with good old http? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63

Comment: Is the server and client on different machines? Different domains?

Comment: The server and client are on different machines, both connected by a common WAN. I've updated the main thread with new info.

Comment: (a) Your title is misleading, inviting answers concerning the Flash plugin, whereas your question actually concerns the AIR runtime (not mentioned in your tags). These products have completely different security models. (b) you should reinstate your full question and post your answer as an answer, rather than an answer that says that the answer is in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your notes spender, I already revised my posts.

Comment: @josemartinsma , dv duely removed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this and updated this post with a sample.

**UPDATED & SOLVED**:
I wanted to send files from a C# server to AS3 Clients using sockets in a Local Network. I had some trouble finding out how to do it, but I managed to do so.

**Server (C#):**
1 - I create a `TcpListener` that listens for new clients with any IP in that network to the specified port number;
2 - When a new client connects I create a `Thread` to handle it;
3 - In that `Thread` I send the data I want to. In this case that data is divided in two parts, the first is a 4 `bytearray` that contains the size of the file I want to send, and the second is a `bytearray` of the file itself;
4 - After the data is sent I close that client connection;

**Client (AS3):**
1 - First of all I convert my `bytearrays` to `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, since AIR is by default `BIG_ENDIAN` and the data I get from the server is `LITTLE_ENDIAN`;
2 - Add the events to the socket connection and conect to the server;
3 - On the `onResponse` function I receive the socket packages to a `bytearray`;
4 - Save that `bytearray` into a file;

The last part on the client was the trickiest one, because it took me some time to figure out that AIR is `BIG_ENDIAN` by default, and how to read the packages.
So basically, what I do is, on the first package that comes in I read the first 4 bytes to a `bytearray` and then convert that to an `int`, which gives me my total file size. I use this to know when there are no more packages to receive and therefore finish the connection and save the file. The rest of the first package and subsequent packages are added to a `bytearray` that will store that file data itself. The workaround here is to start writing on the beggining the first time a package is received and then add the subsequent packages where the last one left off, i.e., first time I write from the 0 to 65321, second one I'll have to write from the 65321 to XXXX, and so on.

The file is being saved to the MyDocuments folder.

I'm unsure if this is the best method to do this, since I'm rather new to socket connection, however this works for me and I tested with files up to 165MB and it works. It supports multiple client connections and is pretty basic, but this is a starting point, not a finish line.

I hope this can help others as it helped me, since I did not find anything like it on the web (regarding file transfer not C# -> AS3 connection).

If someone wants to input some info or needs clarification on something, please feel free to ask.

Last but no least, sample can be downloaded here: http://sdrv.ms/W5mSs9 (Server in C# Express 2010 and Client in Flash Builder 4.6 with Flex SDK 4.6.0)

In case the sample in the link above ever dies out here is the

ActionScript 3 Source Code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Endian;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class FileTransferLocal extends Sprite
    {
        private var socket:Socket = new Socket();
        private var file:File;
        private var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        private var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        private var fileSize:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        private var fileDataPosition:int = new int();
        private var fileDataFlag:int = new int();
        private var fileSizeFlag:int = new int();
        private var fileSizeCounter:int = new int();

        private var fileDataPreviousPosition:int = new int();

        private var myText:TextField = new TextField();


        public function FileTransferLocal()
        {           
            try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };

            // Convert bytearray to Little Endian
            fileSize.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
            fileData.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
            socket.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

            fileSizeFlag = 0;
            fileDataFlag = 0;

            myText.width = 150;
            myText.height = 150;
            myText.x = 200;
            myText.y = 200;

            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
            socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
            socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);

            // Put the IP and port of the server
            socket.connect("10.1.1.211", 5656);
        }

        private function onConnect(e:Event):void {
            trace("onConnect\n");
        }

        private function onClose(e:Event):void {
            trace("onClose");
            socket.close();
        }

        private function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("IO Error: "+e);
        }

        private function onSecError(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("Security Error: "+e);
        }

        private function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {         

            if(!fileSizeFlag) {
                socket.readBytes(fileSize, 0, 4);
                fileSize.position = 0;
                fileSizeFlag = 1;
                fileSizeCounter = fileSize.readInt();
                trace("fileSizeCounter -> " + fileSizeCounter);
            }

            trace("---- New package ----> " + socket.bytesAvailable);

            if(fileSizeCounter > 0) {
                fileSizeCounter -= socket.bytesAvailable;

                if(fileDataPosition != 0) {
                    fileDataPreviousPosition += fileDataPosition;
                }

                if(fileData.length == 0) {
                    fileDataPreviousPosition = socket.bytesAvailable;
                    socket.readBytes(fileData, 0, socket.bytesAvailable);
                } else {
                    fileDataPosition = socket.bytesAvailable;
                    socket.readBytes(fileData, fileDataPreviousPosition, socket.bytesAvailable);
                }
            }

            // Saves the file
            if(fileSizeCounter == 0) {
                trace("File total size" + fileData.length);
                file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.mp3");
                fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(fileData);
                fs.close();

                myText.text = "File successefully\nreceived!";
                addChild(myText);

            }
            // Is still receiving packages
            else {
                myText.text = "Receiving file...";
                addChild(myText);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In C# create a new Windows Application
add a
ListBox call it statusList
Label call it port
Label call it status

C# Source code in Sample Above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ServerThread
{
    public partial class ServerThread : Form
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;

        public ServerThread()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Port number
            int portNumber = 5656;
            port.Text = portNumber.ToString();

            // Create a TcpListener to cover all existent IP addresses with that port
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
            // Create a Thread to listen to clients
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();

        }

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                // Blocks until a client has conected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                // Create a Thread to handle the conected client communication
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            // Receive data
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Sending data
                    string filePath = "send/mysong.mp3"; // Your File Path;
                    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); // The size of your file
                    byte[] fileSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileData.Length); // The size of yout file converted to a 4 byte array
                    byte[] clientData = new byte[fileSize.Length + fileData.Length]; // The total byte size of the data to be sent

                    fileSize.CopyTo(clientData, 0); // Copy to the file size byte array to the sending array (clientData) beginning the in the 0 index
                    fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4); // Copy to the file data byte array to the sending array (clientData) beginning the in the 4 index

                    // Send the data to the client
                    clientStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                    clientStream.Flush();


                    // Debug for the ListBox
                    if (statusList.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        statusList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                            statusList.Items.Add("Client IP: " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                            statusList.Items.Add("Client Data size: " + clientData.Length);
                        }));
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    // 
                    break;
                }

                if (statusList.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    statusList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        statusList.Items.Add("File successefully sent!");
                    }));
                }

                // Close the client
                tcpClient.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```